# Setting button image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimage, mpmovieplayercontroller

**Solved:** I'm a complete idiot. I was previously using two buttons (play and pause) and hiding them rather than changing the one button's image. I stupidly overlooked this line of code: `playButton.hidden = YES`.

I'm building custom `MPMoviePlayerController` controls. I'm trying to set a button's image to `pause.png` when `MPMoviePlaybackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying`. Else, it should set to `play.png`. This statement runs every half second in the same method  `currentPlaybackTime` is set to a `UILabel`.

For some reason, it will not set to `pause.png`. The button just disappears. Although, the condition logs `Playing` and `not playing` correctly.

.h

```
@property (retain) UIImage *playBtnBG;
@property (retain) UIImage *pauseBtnBG;
```

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
playBtnBG = [UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"];
pauseBtnBG = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"];
}


- (void)updatePlaybackTime:(NSTimer*)theTimer 
{
if (!sliding) {
    int playbackTime = moviePlayer.currentPlaybackTime; 

    timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%02d", (playbackTime / 60), (playbackTime % 60)];
    playbackSlider.value = playbackTime;
}

if (moviePlayer.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying) {
    NSLog(@"Playing");
[playButton setImage:pauseBtnBG forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else {
    NSLog(@"not playing");
    [playButton setImage:playBtnBG forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
}
```

Comment: I always suggest running a clean on your project when images don't come up, since I have had the exact same thing happen to me. You might also go to the image in XCode and check on the file inspector tab, making sure that the box next to your project is checked under "Target membership"

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting the same result after running a clean and checking target memberships.

Answer (score 0):

one possibility is that u are not connecting buttons to file owner if u are creating button from xibs  try this and have fun :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 


                                        selector:@selector(moviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChange:) 
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification 
                                           object:nil];

//myPlayer is MPMoviePlayerController declared in header
myPlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:myaudioUrl];
myPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone; 
[myPlayer prepareToPlay];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayerLoadStateChanged:) 
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification 
                                           object:nil];
}

- (void) moviePlayerLoadStateChanged:(NSNotification*)notification {
　　　　　if ([myPlayer loadState] != MPMovieLoadStateUnknown) {
    [[NSNotificationCenter  defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
                                                     name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification 
                                                   object:nil];
    [myPlayer play];
}

}

-(void) moviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChange:(NSNotification*)notification {

NSLog(@"playbackDidChanged");
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = notification.object;
MPMoviePlaybackState playbackState = moviePlayer.playbackState;
if(playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped) {
    NSLog(@"MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped");
} else if(playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying) {
    NSLog(@"MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying");
 [playButton setImage:pauseBtnBG forState:UIControlStateNormal];
} else if(playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused) {
    NSLog(@"MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused");
[playButton setImage:playBtnBG forState:UIControlStateNormal];
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try using the `setBackground:` method.

```
[playButton setBackgroundImage:pauseBtnBG forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```